# How to get the reference of recursive components in Vue3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I have a component (`Group`) which can have recursive components. Within this component there is another component (`ButtonsContainer`). The `ButtonsContainer` component exposes functions to focus first and last buttons. What I want is to get the reference of the first group and the last group, including the recursive ones. How can I achieve this? I tried with a recursive function but the maximum call stack size exceeded.

Below is the `Group` component. I omitted the `ButtonsContainer` component because it has no special functionality, just displaying the buttons in a grid.

`Component Group`:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

const props = defineProps<{
    group: Group
}>();

const buttonsContainerRef = ref<InstanceType<typeof ButtonsContainer> | null>(null);
const firstGroupRef       = ref<InstanceType<typeof Group> | null>(null);
const lastNestedGroupRef  = ref<InstanceType<typeof Group> | null>(null);

function getLastButtonsContainerRef(): Ref<InstanceType<typeof ButtonsContainer> | null> | undefined {
    if (props.group.groups.length > 0) {
        // return getLastButtonsContainerRef(); // still does not work:(
        getLastButtonsContainerRef();
    } else {
        return buttonsContainerRef;
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-if="group.buttons.length > 0 && !props.group.collapsed">
            <ButtonsContainer
                :buttons="group.buttons"
                ref="buttonsContainerRef"
            />
        </li>
        <li
            v-if="group.groups.length > 0 && !props.group.collapsed"
            v-for="nestedGroup in group.groups"
            :key="nestedGroup.uuid"
        >
            <Group
                :group="nestedGroup"
                class="nested-group"
            />
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

How do I get the reference for the first group and for the last one (including the nested ones)? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the nested `refs` you will need to traverse the tree yourself.

There is no ready to use solution for it.

Here is very basic example of going through `refs` including all nested children.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const CompB = {
  props: ['id'],
  setup(props) {
    const name = "CompB"
    return { name } 
  },
  template: '<div class="b">CompB, id:<b>{{id}}</b></div>'
}

const CompA = {
  components: { CompB },
  props: ['id'],
  setup(props) {
    const name = "CompA"
    const child = ref(null)   
    return { name, child } 
  },
  template: '<div class="a">CompA, id:<b>{{id}}</b><CompB ref="child" :id="`${id}.1`" /></div>'
}

const App = { 
  components: { CompA },
  setup(props) {
    const refs = ref([])
    const showRefs = (ref) => {
       if (!ref) {
          for(var i = 0; i < refs.value.length; i++) {
            console.log(`Name: ${refs.value[i].name}, id: ${refs.value[i].id}`);
            if (refs.value[i].child) showRefs(refs.value[i].child)
          }
       } else {
          console.log(`Name: ${ref.name}, id: ${ref.id}`);
       }
    }
    return { refs, showRefs } 
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
.a { 
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
 }
.b { 
  background-color: lightyellow;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
<button @click="showRefs()">Show refs</button><br/>
<comp-a v-for="n in 3" :id="n" ref="refs"></comp-a>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```